# What should be the url in browser when starts a rails app in amazon EC2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a rails app in Amazon EC2. After that I used

```
rails s
```

The server starts. But what should be the url to put in browser? I mean in browser, how can I view that app ? Please share with me if anyone have any idea on it.

Comment: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000, your ip address followed with the port

Comment: You should set the production environment for ec2 instance. Follow this guide http://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-rails-with-phusion-passenger-and-nginx-in-5-minutes/

Comment: @RBS: thanks, which IP? public or private? In EC2 there are two ip address.

Comment: @usmanali: thanks, useful guide,  but I want to run it using webrick first.

Comment: Check the IP you got assigned then .. add `http://<ip>/<root>` url..

Answer (score 1):

You need to open port 3000 in amazon ec2. You will get option of adding rules, adding rule and opening port will do the job.

then

```
 ip-address:3000 (will do job)
```

Comment: My inbound port is 80, what should i do ?

Comment: Add another inbound rule...take port 3000...add protocol 'TCP' and Type 'Custom TCP Rule'

Comment: cant add, when i select HTTP, it takes port 80 automatically

Comment: Why you are selecting HTTP, select Custom TCP Rule?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. What I did is
run the server like this:

```
rails s -b ipaddress
```

And in browser: (Public DNS from amazon EC2:3000)

```
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000
```